# I don't have an SSD but express cache service is running on windows 10 and consuming resources

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hard-drive-cache

Is it normal to have this service running on a PC without SSD? Is it a legitimate process or should I be worried about it?

Comment: `Express Cache` does not appear in the list of services on my virgin installation of Windows 10.  If this services exists on your system, then it's been installed, without knowing what it belongs to it's impossible to say if its **legitimate.**

Comment: Express Cache is installed when you use OEM software.  If you don't have a SSD, then remove the software that installed the service, and call it a day.